# How to create an Object with all attributes of a html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom

Here is my test code, extracted from a form I'm building:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script>
function ini(){
    console.log("Element dump:");
    var elem = document.querySelector('form[name="form"] input[name="dataNasc"]');
    for(var i in elem){
        console.log(i+":"+elem[i]);
    }
    console.log("Form element dump:");
    var Form = document.forms["form"];
    var input = Form.dataNasc;
    for(var i in input){
        console.log(i+":"+input[i]);
    }
}
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="ini();">
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
                <label for="dataNasc">Data Nasc.</label>
                <input type="text" name="dataNasc" maxlength="10" required="required" tipo="data" value="{dataNasc}" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In both cases that I pick the input tag (ini function), the attribute "tipo" is not listed. The property returns "undefined". It seams an object is created using the information in the tag, not a conversion "tag to object". Using outerHTML, I can do it manually (hope this property is cross-browser), but I'm wondering if there is a way using JavaScript resources... How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a reference to the element, you can iterate over its `attributes` NamedNodeMap to discover all of its attributes.  So for example and assuming there will only be one matching element matching your selector...

```
var elt=document.querySelector('form[name="form"] input[name="dataNasc"]'),
    attrs=elt ? elt.attributes : [];

for(var i=0; i<attrs.length; i++) {
    console.log('attr "'+attrs[i].name+'" contains "'+attrs[i].value+'"');
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I did think about attributes, but in a xml context that is not working because the form is irregular (won't parse). By the way, did you test it? There is another attributes with strange names including one undefined=undefined. Bizarre! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I tested the solution in modern versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari. And while `{undefined:undefined}` might not be legal JSON, I'm sure it's an artifact of the underlying engine and can safely be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function ini(){
    console.log("Element dump:");
    var elem = document.querySelector('form[name="form"] input[name="dataNasc"]');
    for(var i in elem){
        console.log(i+":"+elem[i]);
    }
     console.log("Form element dump:");
    var Form = document.forms["form"];
    var input = Form.dataNasc;
     var myObj = {};
     for(var i in input){
         myObj[i] = input[i];
    }
 }
```

Comment: You're just making a copy of input object that does not have "tipo" property.

Comment: You're also copying lots of extraneous values that have nothing to do with the element's defined attributes.